# Error in Importing CSV file which have large white spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, flat-file

While i importing large CSV file through SSMS it throws error like truncation may occur...even when i took only one row from original csv file to another csv file and start importing ends in failure...when i delete extra white spaces manually in duplicate CSV file which contains single row with headers it importing successfully....So please guide me how to import that orginal Large CSV File with extra whitespaces...

[image]

**Note:** I used `varchar(max)` and `text` datatypes for entire table and still i get same error

Below i mention that particular original row which i get error. here delimiters are pipe('|')

```
Column1  |comment                                                                         |column3 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        |RGA 103238                                                                      |017
```

manually edited above row which works for me

```
Column1  |comment     |column3 
-------------------------------
1        |RGA 103238  |017
```

Comment: Did your target table has enough datalength to withhold incoming data, later we can update the table using LTRIM and RTRIM once we import into tables.

Comment: Iam creating new table and pulling data with `varchar(max)` and `text` data types too...but still i get same error

Comment: which error? there is no error message in your post. please post the code you are using to import.

Answer (score 0):

use TRIM function on this as this will remove whitespace .
Varchar is nothing to do with it as its only remove the extra memory space if any.

Comment: Without pulling data into sql table from CSV how could i trim those columns ?

Comment: use sql* loader to pull the data in the oracle table and in the loader control file u can do a trim on that particular column.

Comment: Yes guys i facing this issue in MS SQL while using Import/Export Wizard............Not in oracle